# Ajax Toolkit not working on website deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a working website on my local machine. I decided to buy some hosting and upload the current version, updating it as I work. Everything works on my local machine, there are just uncompleted pages. However, when I uploaded the site to godaddy, ReflectionTypeLoadException.

Here's the stack trace:

```
[ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() +4
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +70
   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerConfig..cctor() +68

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerConfig' threw an exception.]
   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager..ctor() +62
   ASP.basic_master.__BuildControlScriptManager1() in g:\PleskVhosts\ethentia.com\httpdocs\Basic.master:24
   ASP.basic_master.__BuildControlform1() in g:\PleskVhosts\ethentia.com\httpdocs\Basic.master:22
   ASP.basic_master.__BuildControlTree(basic_master __ctrl) in g:\PleskVhosts\ethentia.com\httpdocs\Basic.master:1
   ASP.basic_master.FrameworkInitialize() in g:\PleskVhosts\ethentia.com\httpdocs\Basic.master.cs:912308
   System.Web.UI.UserControl.InitializeAsUserControlInternal() +32
   System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection) +655
   System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() +14
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +45
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +335
```

I have make sure that I included the Ajax dlls in my Bin folder. I have tried reloading and rebuilding my site. I am using the most current version of Ajax and ASP. [Here](http://ethentia.com/) is my site url with the stack trace if anyone wants to see it.

Thanks for any help.

--felesmorits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing research on internet, I found ajax control toolkit requires full trust to function. The default trust on server is medium, you need to change that to full. Add `<trust level="Full" />` under system.web in your web.config.

http://support.winhost.com/KB/a657/changing-the-default-aspnet-trust-level.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Find the System.Web.Extensions.dll file and copy it over to the bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, having Ajax controls working locally but wasn't in actual environment. Tried most of the things out there but none worked for me.

In fact, I was passing by a deployment via `Plesk` who has got a Web Firewall that discards these calls namely calls to `ScriptRessource.axd` or `WebRessource.axd`. Disabling `ModSecurity` of Plesk did the trick for me. However it is preferable to discard only the rule concerning these resources. But I did not yet find out how to do that.
I posted this information to help any who could have a similar problem.